# Drupal module shows as installed but table not in schema

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on an API that pulls data from a Drupal site. Everything has gone pretty well I normally use Drupal Bootstrap to load Drupal use the functions I need then spit out a JSON array. I am having one issue though with a module, for some reason Drupal's schema doesn't seem to think the table exists. The module I am working with is VotingApi.

So in my API call I connect to the drupal db. Then if I run:

```
print_r(module_list());
```

I get a big list of modules installed and `votingapi` is included. If I run:

```
var_dump(module_exists('voting_api'));
```

I get a `true` response. I can also run:

```
var_dump(db_table_exists('votingapi_vote'));
```

And get a `true` response. However if I run:

```
print_r(drupal_get_complete_schema(true));
```

The `votingapi_vote` and `votingapi_cache` tables don't show up in the list. So then when I try to write a record to those tables with `drupal_write_record()` it doesn't work because that function checks the schema to see if the table exists. I have tried clearing the schema cache like this before I call `drupal_get_complete_schema()`:

```
cache_clear_all('schema', 'cache');
```

It doesn't help, when it is rebuilt from the API the voting tables never show up. If I go into Drupal's admin and Clear All Cache then the table schema is rebuilt correctly and includes the voting tables. Any ideas on how I can get the schema to rebuild correct for the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It had to do with using MultiSite apparently when you use multisite and bootstrap it will only bootstrap to the main site. I found an article talking about it here https://drupal.org/node/2080819

Basically you need to override what the system variable is for the url so that it will bootstrap to the correct site.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/path/to/drupal');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
$variables['url'] = 'http://subsite1.example.com/';
drupal_override_server_variables($variables);
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```